# If $g\circ f$ is onto, and $g$ is into, is true that $f$ is onto?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, function-and-relation-composition

I was faced by this question some time ago, and it keeps me thinking:

> If $g\circ f$ is onto, and $g$ is into, prove that $f$ is onto.

In this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11573/prove-if-g-circ-f-is-onto-and-g-is-1-1-then-f-is-onto) we can find something very close, but with $g$ being $1-1$, which is not my case here (if it was, it would be easy). Then, I was thinking if this is necessarilly true, trying to find some counter example.

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "$g$ is into"?

Comment: Hi, @absolute0 I mean that $g$ is injective. (This is translated, the original language of the question is portuguese).

Comment: But 1-1 means injective exactly...

Comment: @AlexProvost I thought that $1-1$ means bijective. Thanks for it!

Comment: If $g$ is injective you can use the proof in your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y$ be a point in the codomain of $f$. Then $g(y)$ is defined, in the codomain of $g \circ f$ and so there is some $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $g(f(x)) = g(y)$. It follows that $y=f(x)$ as $g$ is injective (or "into"). So $y$ is a value of $f$ and we're done.

Note that 1-1 = into = injective, so the quoted proof actually goes through.